# Script to get images in folder with dimensions printed to a .txt file

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch, script

As title goes, is there a script for Win 7 to get printed on a .txt file all the images (JPG, PNG, GIF ecc) inside a folder along with "filename" and "pixels dimension"? 
I've tried with `dir` on command line but only lists name, file size ecc..

---

### Solution with ExifTool

The best deal imo, with the command already coded in the file name of the .exe its totally a drag and drop script to use wherever you want!

**Update**
For convenience, I've slightly modified the inline file name of the exe to this

```
ExifTool(-FileName -Imagesize -r -T -w+! %0finfo.txt -ext jpg --ext exe .).exe
```

This way I've reduced to the minimum the .txt output to a single line per image (`-T`) and added a recursive option (`-r`) so that it can process subfolders too.

---

### Solution with ImageMagick

I've placed below my solution with ImageMagick, is pretty quick and simple but ofc requires the library installed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [ExifTool](http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) (portable executable renamed to *exiftool.exe*):

```
exiftool -ImageSize -r .
```

Here *ImageSize* is the tag name you're interested in and will print *Image Width x Image Height*. The `-r` switch makes it recursively process files in subdirectories.

Custom [output string format](http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/exiftool_pod.html#input_output_text_formatting) is simple as well. For example:

```
exiftool -p "Image Name: \"$FileName\"$/Image Size: $ImageSize$/" -r .
```

In this case the tag names are preceded by $. `$/` prints a newline.

Note: The commands above have to be typed at the command prompt. To redirect the output to a text file you can append `> Details.txt` to them.

---

If you want to simply run the program and have it write a text file with the relevant image details, you can [rename the executable](http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/index.html#running) as follows:

```
ExifTool(-FileName -Imagesize -w+! %0fDetails.txt -ext gif --ext exe .).exe
```

This will write all console output (`-w`) to a file named *Details.txt* in the current directory. In this case the output will consist of the image names and sizes for all GIFs in the current directory. Further details about the `-w` parameter, including the meaning of `+`, `!` and `%0f` are available at the documentation link above.

You can *include* more extensions to be processed using `-ext jpg -ext png` and so on, or delete `-ext gif` altogether to make it read all supported file types (including non-images which you may not want).

`--ext exe` is used to *exclude* all EXEs (so that the program's own executable isn't included in the report).

`-r` can of course be added to enable recursive processing.

There is *lots* more you can do with the program given how ridiculously powerful it is (and extensible too given that the full Perl source is freely available)!

Comment: Looks interesting but I'm a bit stuck using it, I've been able to make it output the sizes inside the command window only after I've opened the images with drag-drop. How can I make it create a .txt file with the output? How can I simply drop the .exe in the folder double click and do the magic?  Thank you for your answer

Comment: @Gruber: Those commands actually have to be typed at the command prompt. To redirect to a text file you can add `> Details.txt` to the end of the commands. I have a far better one-click solution for your problem however. See the edited answer above.

Comment: Now that's amazing! Thank you for extending your answer with the script in the .exe file name, ridiculously handy! :)

Comment: @Gruber: You're welcome, glad you found it useful. :)

Answer (score 2):

Ok solution with **ImageMagick**, simple and quick (but ofc requires the library).

Open the cmd line in the folder you are interested (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>RightClick</kbd> inside your folder window and select "Open command window here"), then in the cmd prompt use this

```
identify -format "%f %wx%h\r" *.jpg > info.txt
```

Calls for `%f filename`, `%w width` and `%h height` formatted like "WIDTHxHEIGHT"

More info here http://www.imagemagick.org/script/escape.php

Answer (score 1):

There a [PowerShell script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Retrieve-file-metadata-6814c8ba) below that should do it; just change the directories for list and output. I tested under Windows 8.1 and Windows PowerShellISE.

```
param( $folder = "E:\My Pictures", $outputFile = "E:\details.txt" )
$objShell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$fileList = @()
$attrList = @{}
$details = ( "Dimensions" )
$objFolder = $objShell.namespace($folder)
for ($attr = 0 ; $attr  -le 500; $attr++)
{
    $attrName = $objFolder.getDetailsOf($objFolder.items, $attr)
    if ( $attrName -and ( -not $attrList.Contains($attrName) ))
    {
        $attrList.add( $attrName, $attr )
    }
}
dir $folder -Recurse -Directory | ForEach-Object{
    $objFolder = $objShell.namespace($_.FullName)
    foreach($file in $objFolder.items())
    {
        foreach( $attr in $details)
        {
            $attrValue = $objFolder.getDetailsOf($file, $attrList[$attr])
            if ( $attrValue )
            {
                Add-Member -InputObject $file -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $("A_" + $attr) -value $attrValue
            }
        }
        $fileList += $file
        $fileList.Count
    }
}
$fileList | Export-Csv $outputFile -Delimiter ','
$fileList | Format-Table
```

Comment: This is not working since you set the folders. I'd like to have it works in whatever folder I drop the file script to. How can this be modified?

Comment: Use ".' for the current directory, so line 1 becomes: **param( $folder = ".", $outputFile = "details.txt" )**